# Get contact details from article override

Tags: joomla-3.x, user, template-override, contact

I need to display the contact information of a contact on an article override (addresse, phone number...).
I can get the user with : `$user = JFactory::getUser();` but how can I get a user contact details?

I tried using this :

```
JTable::addIncludePath(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_contact/tables');
$contact = JTable::getInstance('contact_details');    

echo '<pre>'; print_r($contact); echo '</pre>';
```

But it doesn't output anything.

Answer (score 3):

You will firstly need to retrieve the user ID like so:

```
$id = JFactory::getUser()->id;
```

Then get the array of profile data, like so:

```
$profile = JUserHelper::getProfile($id)->profile;
```

You can now access any of the data:

```
echo $profile['address1'];
echo $profile['address2'];
echo $profile['city'];
echo $profile['region'];
echo $profile['country'];
echo $profile['postal_code'];
echo $profile['phone'];
echo $profile['website'];
echo $profile['favoritebook'];
echo $profile['aboutme'];
echo $profile['dob'];
```

You need to make sure you're logged in, else you won't be able to get the information:

Here's the full code with a sanity check:

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();

if (!$user->guest)
{
    $profile = JUserHelper::getProfile($user->id)->profile;

    echo $profile['address1'];
    echo $profile['address2'];
    echo $profile['city'];
    echo $profile['region'];
    echo $profile['country'];
    echo $profile['postal_code'];
    echo $profile['phone'];
    echo $profile['website'];
    echo $profile['favoritebook'];
    echo $profile['aboutme'];
    echo $profile['dob'];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I have tested this but it outputs `Undefined property: Joomla\CMS\Object\CMSObject::$profile`. I removed `->profile` and the outputed array is : `Joomla\CMS\Object\CMSObject Object ( [_errors:protected] => Array ( ) [id] => 142 )`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @web-tiki - You'll get this error if you're not logged in. I've updated the answer with a sanity check.

Comment: Thx for the info. I didn't have the profile plugin enabled as I wanted to use the com_contact fields instead of the user profile. For this particular project, I can use the profile plugin thanks to your code but is there a way to get the contact information from the com_contact in an article override?

Comment: On a side note, I know before hand the id of the user I need to show as it the same for everyone. An example of what I am trying to do is "display the address of a site owner in the footer under the title of an article"

Answer (score 1):

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('*')->from('#__contact_details')->where('user_id = '.(int)$user->id);
$db->setQuery($query);
$contacts = $db->loadObjectList(); 
/* one user can be associated with multiple contacts */
if($contacts) {
    /* do stuff with the contact records */
}
```

Comment: Good edit mickmackusa !